# How do I portray characters with a bum leg properly in an action game like Devil May Cry, without making him a liability?

Tags: game-design

Right now, I'm designing a character for a 2D action platformer game. The problem is that said character has a bum leg due to an accident a few years prior to the game's setting, but was the first one to be dragged into a dungeon formed by the newly developing incident, and had to escape on his own.

What I've thought about until now about this:

1. The character will move slower than the normal movement speed, cannot double jump, and have a lower jump height than the normal jump height.
2. However, he would use a sword that doubles as a retractable whip, allowing his melee attacks to have a wide coverage. Said sword-whip has low damage by default, however.
3. There's also that his melee attacks are less focused on launching enemies upwards and more focused on knocking them back - and maybe apply bleeding (non-elemental damage over time).
4. He would also have a shotgun that can be 'charged' to maximize the damage output, very much like the Gunslinger Style Shotgun in DMC3 and 4.

My problem is that this character will be one from around eight (for now), and the other seven characters don't have such a disability - two of them I intend to have the ability to glide mid-air.

The game will have a feature of switching between three characters chosen to engage the other dungeons, so he can be switched out for sections that require double jumping, but I'm not sure that's an optimal solution, especially considering the lower damage his weapon deals (making him a non-optimal pick for boss battles).

Should I just make each character fulfill a specific niche in terms of mobility options, melee attack options, and ranged attack options? How does one design the map and bosses for these cases, without making it seem like giving him too much of a break?

P.S. Can a grappling hook be involved, without ending up making him the best option to navigate the map (like refreshing it only after landing)?

EDIT: I also have a thought of integrating this grappling hook into the sword-whip, being able to pull enemies towards him, or him towards them. Is it possible to use this as a melee charge attack? Because I still think that it doesn't feel right.

Comment: This sounds like something you would need to figure out through rigorous playtesting.

Comment: I see a couple of votes to close this question as primarily opinion-based, but I think it has the hallmarks outlined in the [game-design tag guidance](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/tags/game-design/info): it establishes the game context, explains the feature being developed, defines the desired outcome (this character's disability is represented and they remain a viable choice to include in a player party), and asks for strategies to achieve that goal. To help get answers, I'd recommend editing to give more detail on how your mechanics work so we can better evaluate a character's viability

Comment: @DMGregory OK, which part of the mechanics I've described needs more detail?

Comment: I don't know. You know more about your mechanics than we do! If you had to break down a recipe or formula for what makes a viable adventurer party in your game, what would go into it?